# MAP files don't include INLINE functions

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker

Is there any way to include inline functions in MAP files. In essence is there any way to include non public symbols in a map file?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is missing platform and compiler used.

Answer (score 1):

When functions are inlined, they are not present in the final compilation unit as a symbolic function to be called. When inlined, the compiler places the code directly into the caller, so if this was inlined:

```
  inline int multiply(int a, int b)
  {
      return a*b
  }

  int main() 
  {
      printf("%i", multiply(a,b));
  }
```

Inlining causes multiply as a symbol in the compiled product to go away, giving the same as:

```
  int main() 
  {
      printf("%i", a * b);
  }
```

If you always want the function to appear as a symbol in the final product **remove the inlines**. Your compiler may have a switch that would make it easy to remove inlines in a build.

Comment: yeah, that is what i have decided. Don't treat inline as inline.

Answer (score 0):

Inline functions are being *inlined*. There is no call to them *if* they get inlined. They'll be spliced into the binary code where ever a call would "normally" happen.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C (aka C99) has a well defined way to have a symbol for an `inline` function emitted. Just put the definition (with the `inline`) in a .h file and a declaration (no function body) without `inline` in just one compilation unit (.c file).

Comment: Thaks for your reply. I am on vs2005 :( and can't use this feature. As u may know vs2005 does not support C99.

Comment: First, please add such information in the future to your question. If you ask about C, you get an answer about the current standard. Then, for your special case `inline` itself is part of C99 and was not present in C89. In that sense it is an extension of C89. Your compiler documentation should contain information about such extensions. Usually using something like `inline static` works reasonably well.